# AVR Assembly - Timer1 input capture while stopped?

Tags: assembly, avr

I am using `Timer1` in Input Capture mode on an `atmega328` to measure the period duration of a PDM encoded signal (for controlling model railways according to DCC NMRA standards). See image:
[image]
The capture is triggered on the falling edge of the signal on pin `ICP1`.
`TCNT1` is reset after each capture, in order to avoid 16-bit subtraction (not to mention occupying 4 registers) to obtain the pulse duration.

**My question is:**

Is the `TIMER1 CAPTURE` interrupt thrown while the counter is **stopped**? I have not been able to deduce it from the microcontroller datasheet.

If so, I can gain a minor advantage by getting first read = 0x0000. Then I'd start the timer with prescaler set at fCLK_I/O:8.

Has anyone tried this and can lend a hand?

Cheers,

Laura.

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have access to any AVR hardware over Christmas, but by memory - no, the Input Capture interrupts will not be set when the timer is stopped.

However, if your concern is the computational burden of a 16-bit subtract on AVR:

1. Check the generated assembly for a 16-bit subtraction, you'll be surprised how few cycles this takes.
2. Regardless, point 1 is somewhat moot - as you shouldn't be needing to do any subtraction if I've understood your requirement correctly of simply counting time between interrupts? If this is what you need to do, set TCNT=0 as the **last** operation the TIMER1_CAPTURE ISR does. The next time the ISR is executed, read TCNT1 as the **first** thing the ISR does. You now have time between interrupts (assuming no overflow of TCNT1, your prescalar value must be set to ensure the timer does not overflow given your expected period between pulses/ISRs).

Assuming avr-gcc, you can assign the value of TCNT1 into either a volatile global, or volatile file-scope variable as required:

```
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    x = TCNT1;
    TCNT1 = 0;
}
```

Or call some other function inside your ISR that takes TCNT1 as an argument (calling functions in AVR ISRs comes with it's own performance 'challenges', but is still extremely common. See this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149578/how-does-the-call-stack-operated-during-an-interrupt-on-avr).

```
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    process_the_timer_count(TCNT1);
    TCNT1 = 0;
}
```